# Local function declaration versus pointer to function

Tags: javascript, pointers

```
class Testone{
    constructor(value){
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'doSomething', {
            enumerable: false,
            configurable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: () => {
                //do whatever
            }
        });
    }
} 

const doWhatever = () => {
    //do whatever
} 

class Testtwo{
    constructor(value){
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'doSomething', {
            enumerable: false,
            configurable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: doWhatever
        });
    }
}
```

My thought is that `Testtwo` should be more efficient, since `doWhatever` would only exist in memory once then get pointed to by every instance of `Testtwo`. `Testone` would instantiate a new anonymous function for each new instance.

1. Does `Testone` actually create a new anonymous function each time? Is `Testtwo` therefor more efficient or is it also creating separate instances of `doWhatever`?
2. Am I missing some major caveat to one over the other (other than variable scope)?

My benchmarking consistently shows ~2% difference in instantiation time, with `Testtwo` indeed being faster... but that's not exactly confirmation.

Comment: Arrow function cannot be instantiated using the `new` operator therefore not ideal to construct your own prototypes with. `function` is the base for prototypes, whereas `class` model is considered just syntactic sugar. For more info head to: [MDN - Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) - more specifically: [Binding this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#binding_this_with_prototype_and_static_methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `Testone` create new `doSomething` function every time, but `Testtwo` uses existing one.

Proof:

```js
class Testone{
    constructor(value){
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'doSomething', {
            enumerable: false,
            configurable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: () => {
                //do whatever
            }
        });
    }
} 

const doWhatever = () => {
    //do whatever
}

class Testtwo{
    constructor(value){
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'doSomething', {
            enumerable: false,
            configurable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: doWhatever
        });
    }
}

const f1 = new Testone()
const f2 = new Testone()
console.log('Testone', f1.doSomething === f2.doSomething)

const s1 = new Testtwo()
const s2 = new Testtwo()
console.log('Testtwo', s1.doSomething === s2.doSomething)
```